# Php Shell Exec doesnt work

Tags: php, bash, raspberry-pi, vlc

i've got a site on my raspberry pi with remote launching music.

The script in .php looks like this:

```
<?php $message=shell_exec("cvlc /home/pi/1373_128.m3u &");
header('Location:index.html'); ?>
```

It is working from a command line ( php5 radioon.php )

But when I am trying to launch it from website it is not, any ideas what may be wrong? The php script itself is fine, it is working when it comes to turn on light in room etc.

Comment: Does the webserver user have permission to `/home/pi/` and is `cvlc` in it's path?

Comment: @AbraCadaver how I can check it?

I moved it to: 

$message=shell_exec("cvlc /var/www/html/1373_128.m3u &");

Still doesnt work

Comment: Test with just `var_dump(shell_exec("cvlc /home/pi/1373_128.m3u &"))` and no header redirect! Tip:`whoami` is the linux cmd to get the current username. And i dont thing www-data has access to /home/*